# Managing and positioning CSS <divs>

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve this:

[image]
...as a format for news articles on my site (runic-paradise.com). You can see I've achieved everything except the orange bits. I'm trying to make the orange bits their own divs so I can put them in colored square backgrounds - to resemble something like this:

[image]

...however, I can't seem to get the divs to do what I want. It ends up messing up the 2 lower divs holding the image and text content. Anyone have any quick tips on how to achieve this? :(

JSFiddle of what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/HDbq6/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="articleshell">
     <div class="articletitle">
     <h4 class="newstitleh4">A shining beacon in the desert - November 5, 2013</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="articleauthor">
     Author
     </div>
     <div class="articleimg">
     <a href="images/EukitoDesertTemple.jpg" data-rel="prettyPhoto[gal]" title="Eukito's Desert Temple"><img src="images/thumbs/EukitoDesertTempleThumb.jpg" width="90" height="90" class="news_thumb" alt="Eukito's Desert Temple" /></a>
     </div>
     <div class="articletext">
     <p>Eukito has completed construction of his desert temple. Of course no temple is complete without a secret passage or two... Stop on by at night to see it shining in the desert!</p>
     </div> 

</div>
```

CSS

```
.articleshell {
    width: 770px;
    max-height: none;
    min-height: 130px;
    padding-top: 5.px;
    padding-right: 5.px;
    padding-bottom: 5.px;
    padding-left: 5.px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    background-color: #564D4D;
}
.articletext {
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    clear: both;
}
.articleimg {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    clear: both;
}
.articletitle {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    float: left;
}
.newstitleh4 {
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
.articleauthor {
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
}
.articlecontent {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Please post your HTML/CSS.

Comment: Please provide more information about your problem, a fiddle would be great if you can create one.

Comment: without code or jsfiddle.....you asking quick tips....yeah debug it!!! :)

Comment: Without seeying your code im **assuming** that you could have a floating problem and you need to clear the float...

Comment: Sorry all :( Added code and a jsfiddle. Appreciate if anyone could maybe undo the -1 on the question :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this ?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5P8YH/1/)

```
.main{width:500px; height:200px; border:1px solid #ccc; background:#f3f3f3; padding:5px;}
#title{width:45%; background:#ccc; border:1px solid #333; display: inline-block;}
.buttons{width:15%; background:orange; display: inline-block; border:1px solid #333;}
.mainContent{ width:100%; color:#ccc; border:1px solid #333; margin-top:5px; height:170px;}



<div class="main">
    <div id="title">Title</div>
        <div class="buttons">Author</div>
        <div class="buttons">Role</div>
        <div class="buttons">Date</div>
    <div class="mainContent"></div> 
</div>
```

The title id have a display:inline-block and div to get the thumb and the text content, that way the "buttons" don't mess up with the content. (I think)